# Running docker Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed:

Tags: python-3.x, docker

Sysinfo:

```
Linux kali 5.10.0-kali7-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.28-1kali1 (2021-04-12) x86_64 GNU/Linux
Kali GNU/Linux Rolling \n \l
Docker version 20.10.5+dfsg1, build 55c4c88
pip 20.3.4 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

Original Issue: https://github.com/mikaelkall/massrecon/issues/8

Goal: **build a docker container for a python script for OSCP**

Script: **https://github.com/mikaelkall/massrecon**

Docker file I created:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.6
WORKDIR /home/OS_85841/Documents/Docker/Massrecon/WorkingDirectory/
FROM kalilinux/kali-bleeding-edge:latest
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install sudo git -y
RUN sudo apt install python3 -y
RUN sudo apt install python3-pip -y
RUN python3 -m pip install --user pipx
RUN python3 -m pipx ensurepath
RUN python3 -m pip install git+https://github.com/mikaelkall/massrecon.git
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN sudo pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN echo "Defaults  secure_path="secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin"" >> /etc/sudoers
RUN apt-get -y autoremove && apt-get -y autoclean
ENTRYPOINT [" python3 ./massrecon.py"]
```

Current Directory I want everything to live in:
**~/Documents/Docker/Massrecon/WorkingDirectory**

Files that live in that directory:
1.) requriements.txt
2.) Dockerfile

Content of Requirements.txt:

```
halo==0.0.28
Paver==1.3.4
configparser==3.5.0
pyOpenSSL==18.0.0
nose==1.3.7
rednose==1.3.0
unittest2==1.1.0
requests==2.20.0
python-docx==0.8.10
```

Command I used to build Docker container:  **sudo docker build -t massrecon .**

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon   5.12kB
Step 1/15 : FROM python:3.6
 ---> 2a09b9410ba8
Step 2/15 : WORKDIR /home/OS_85841/Documents/Docker/Massrecon/WorkingDirectory/
 ---> Running in e4f72f83a82e
Removing intermediate container e4f72f83a82e
 ---> 4d3e8a9971fe
Step 3/15 : FROM kalilinux/kali-bleeding-edge:latest
 ---> 9fe128f7cb87
Step 4/15 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cc5ab43b0f42
Step 5/15 : RUN apt-get install sudo git -y
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ee0e8a6876b3
Step 6/15 : RUN sudo apt install python3 -y
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cde935480a5d
Step 7/15 : RUN sudo apt install python3-pip -y
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ed1056603545
Step 8/15 : RUN python3 -m pip install --user pipx
 ---> Using cache
 ---> dc562ca617b6
Step 9/15 : RUN python3 -m pipx ensurepath
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f7f5475a0310
Step 10/15 : RUN python3 -m pip install git+https://github.com/mikaelkall/massrecon.git
 ---> Running in fc9c4b4bc962
Collecting git+https://github.com/mikaelkall/massrecon.git
  Cloning https://github.com/mikaelkall/massrecon.git to /tmp/pip-req-build-9fzzjoyg
  Running command git clone -q https://github.com/mikaelkall/massrecon.git /tmp/pip-req-build-9fzzjoyg
Collecting Paver==1.3.4                                                                                                                                          
  Using cached Paver-1.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (428 kB)
Collecting configparser==3.5.0
  Using cached configparser-3.5.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting halo==0.0.28
  Using cached halo-0.0.28-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting nose==1.3.7
  Using cached nose-1.3.7-py3-none-any.whl (154 kB)
Collecting pyOpenSSL==18.0.0
  Using cached pyOpenSSL-18.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
Collecting python-docx==0.8.10
  Using cached python_docx-0.8.10-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting rednose==1.3.0
  Using cached rednose-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting requests==2.20.0
  Using cached requests-2.20.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (60 kB)
Collecting unittest2==1.1.0
  Using cached unittest2-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
Collecting six>=1.12.0
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting cursor>=1.2.0
  Using cached cursor-1.3.4-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting colorama>=0.3.9
  Using cached colorama-0.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting log-symbols>=0.0.13
  Using cached log_symbols-0.0.14-py3-none-any.whl (3.1 kB)
Collecting termcolor>=1.1.0
  Using cached termcolor-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting spinners>=0.0.23
  Using cached spinners-0.0.24-py3-none-any.whl (5.5 kB)
Collecting cryptography>=2.2.1
  Using cached cryptography-3.4.8-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_24_x86_64.whl (3.0 MB)
Collecting lxml>=2.3.2
  Using cached lxml-4.6.3-cp39-cp39-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (6.9 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from rednose==1.3.0->massrecon==1.0.3) (52.0.0)
Collecting termstyle>=0.1.7
  Using cached termstyle-0.1.11-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Using cached certifi-2021.5.30-py2.py3-none-any.whl (145 kB)
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1
  Using cached urllib3-1.24.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (118 kB)
Collecting idna<2.8,>=2.5
  Using cached idna-2.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Collecting traceback2
  Using cached traceback2-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting argparse
  Using cached argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Collecting cffi>=1.12
  Using cached cffi-1.14.6-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (405 kB)
Collecting pycparser
  Using cached pycparser-2.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112 kB)
Collecting linecache2
  Using cached linecache2-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: massrecon
  Building wheel for massrecon (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for massrecon (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for massrecon: filename=massrecon-1.0.3-py3-none-any.whl size=20135 sha256=b516977f30f3367cb0b2f52e74d715c3c1d28e903eb9e381b17feed6bba6b54f
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-dne9snhi/wheels/26/a8/5b/60ce79b41d0a0f80e52e165cbe9b5efbf09e32bf70cf96f173
Successfully built massrecon
Installing collected packages: pycparser, linecache2, colorama, cffi, urllib3, traceback2, termstyle, termcolor, spinners, six, lxml, log-symbols, idna, cursor, cryptography, chardet, certifi, argparse, unittest2, requests, rednose, python-docx, pyOpenSSL, Paver, nose, halo, configparser, massrecon
Successfully installed Paver-1.3.4 argparse-1.4.0 certifi-2021.5.30 cffi-1.14.6 chardet-3.0.4 colorama-0.4.4 configparser-3.5.0 cryptography-3.4.8 cursor-1.3.4 halo-0.0.28 idna-2.7 linecache2-1.0.0 log-symbols-0.0.14 lxml-4.6.3 massrecon-1.0.3 nose-1.3.7 pyOpenSSL-18.0.0 pycparser-2.20 python-docx-0.8.10 rednose-1.3.0 requests-2.20.0 six-1.16.0 spinners-0.0.24 termcolor-1.1.0 termstyle-0.1.11 traceback2-1.4.0 unittest2-1.1.0 urllib3-1.24.3
Removing intermediate container fc9c4b4bc962
 ---> 7eb12bac1208
Step 11/15 : COPY requirements.txt ./
 ---> addff8c7c79c
Step 12/15 : RUN sudo pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in eaec3c0f6c60
Requirement already satisfied: halo==0.0.28 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.0.28)
Requirement already satisfied: Paver==1.3.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (1.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: configparser==3.5.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 3)) (3.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyOpenSSL==18.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) (18.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: nose==1.3.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 5)) (1.3.7)
Requirement already satisfied: rednose==1.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 6)) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: unittest2==1.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 7)) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests==2.20.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 8)) (2.20.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-docx==0.8.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 9)) (0.8.10)
Requirement already satisfied: log-symbols>=0.0.13 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from halo==0.0.28->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.0.14)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama>=0.3.9 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from halo==0.0.28->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.12.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from halo==0.0.28->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: spinners>=0.0.23 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from halo==0.0.28->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.0.24)
Requirement already satisfied: cursor>=1.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from halo==0.0.28->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor>=1.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from halo==0.0.28->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=2.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from pyOpenSSL==18.0.0->-r requirements.txt (line 4)) (3.4.8)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml>=2.3.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from python-docx==0.8.10->-r requirements.txt (line 9)) (4.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from rednose==1.3.0->-r requirements.txt (line 6)) (52.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: termstyle>=0.1.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from rednose==1.3.0->-r requirements.txt (line 6)) (0.1.11)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from requests==2.20.0->-r requirements.txt (line 8)) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from requests==2.20.0->-r requirements.txt (line 8)) (1.24.3)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.8,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from requests==2.20.0->-r requirements.txt (line 8)) (2.7)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from requests==2.20.0->-r requirements.txt (line 8)) (2021.5.30)
Requirement already satisfied: traceback2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from unittest2==1.1.0->-r requirements.txt (line 7)) (1.4.0)
Collecting argparse
  Using cached argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.12 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from cryptography>=2.2.1->pyOpenSSL==18.0.0->-r requirements.txt (line 4)) (1.14.6)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography>=2.2.1->pyOpenSSL==18.0.0->-r requirements.txt (line 4)) (2.20)
Requirement already satisfied: linecache2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from traceback2->unittest2==1.1.0->-r requirements.txt (line 7)) (1.0.0)
Installing collected packages: argparse
Successfully installed argparse-1.4.0
Removing intermediate container eaec3c0f6c60
 ---> b56953b24882
Step 13/15 : RUN echo "Defaults secure_path="secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin"" >> /etc/sudoers
 ---> Running in 8a7d20914f71
Removing intermediate container 8a7d20914f71
 ---> 6559ac49b7d4
Step 14/15 : RUN apt-get -y autoremove && apt-get -y autoclean
 ---> Running in d6ade106f0d1
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 22 not upgraded.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Removing intermediate container d6ade106f0d1
 ---> c71f26801d05
Step 15/15 : ENTRYPOINT [" python3 ./massrecon.py"]
 ---> Running in d0e9cb3eb573
Removing intermediate container d0e9cb3eb573
 ---> cf5be7ae27be
Successfully built cf5be7ae27be
Successfully tagged massrecon:latest
```

Command Used to verify docker container:  **sudo docker images**

```
REPOSITORY                     TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
massrecon                      latest    cf5be7ae27be   5 minutes ago   647MB
<none>                         <none>    4d3e8a9971fe   6 minutes ago   902MB
tib3rius/autorecon             latest    9d6f0dd1ce7e   11 hours ago    3.22GB
python                         3.6       2a09b9410ba8   5 days ago      902MB
kalilinux/kali-bleeding-edge   latest    9fe128f7cb87   2 weeks ago     125MB
```

Command used to run docker container: **sudo docker run -it  massrecon**

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: " python3 ./massrecon.py": stat  python3 ./massrecon.py: no such file or directory: unknown.
```

**I been working on this for a few days, my last option is to try out the knowledge base of all IT knowledge stack overflow, All I want to do is create a docker container consisting of the massrecon.py and all the files and dependcies it needs to work fully, any help would be apricated and thanks for taking the time to look**

Comment: The `ENTRYPOINT` line is telling Docker to run exactly `" python3 ./massrecon.py"`, as a single word, with a space at the beginning and a space in the middle; there is no file in `/usr/bin` with exactly that pattern of spaces.  Do you mean perhaps `CMD ["python3", "./massrecon.py"]`, or the simpler shell form?

Comment: (You should also be able to discard most of that Dockerfile; you don't need `sudo` in Docker, and you can start `FROM python:3.6` in many cases instead of recreating its environment on another base image.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I appreciated your response and you taking a look at what I am doing here. This is my first time doing this Docker image so I apologize for lack of knowledge. I will take any advice on how to proper set up a docker file, I updated my Docker file with the suggestions provided above. I received  a new error  this time `$ sudo docker run -it --rm  massrecon python3: can't open file '//./massrecon.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory` I am not sure if this is due to the WORDIR so I removed WORDIR and  update the file with the above suggestions.

Comment: `└─$ sudo docker run -it massrecon
python3: can't open file '//./massrecon.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
`